# Skype integration in OSX Messages

Tags: macos, messages, skype

Just curious to see if there is any possible way to do this but is it possible to get Skype chats to work in OSX Messages?

Since I already use 3 other chat methods in Messages (iMessage, Facebook and Google Talk) running a separate program that chews out so much valuable system resources seems a silly way just to stay in contact with a couple more people.

Comment: have a look at Adium its a client Side App which supports the most well known Chat Services it also still has the Skype plugin (i just can't test know if it is still working) it also has a whatsapp plugin https://adium.im http://www.adiumxtras.com/index.php?a=search&cat_id=9

Answer (score 1):

No. Skype is developed by Microsoft and Apple wants to promote Facetime. I really wish there was way though because I hate the Skype interface but have to use it frequently for my job.

Comment: It should be *theoretically* possible, but it would require skype using undocumented Apple API calls, which they generally don't like people doing too much.

Comment: Actually no. There is a public API for creating Messages.app protocol extensions. So the only thing stopping Microsoft is (probably) business decisions.

Comment: Assuming Skype has some sort of public API, it should theoretically be possible to write a bridge!

Comment: @Fuzzy76 Do you have any link for these API? Thanks!

Comment: Found it! https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/IMServicePluginFrameworkRef/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009478

Comment: Apple seems to have removed the above resource, WaybackMachine link https://web.archive.org/web/20140603161319/https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/IMServicePluginFrameworkRef/index.html